# extract json web service data in Android

Tags: android, json

i have a service web that returns this output:
[49691175,34099427,34099427,107426658,43320654,43320654,43320654,43320654,43320654,43320654,34392131,107298918,107298918,107298918,103363801,103363801]

and i want to extract these BigIntegers in a list in android

```
@GET
@Path("route")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<BigInteger> getitineraire() {
    List<BigInteger> list = iservices.getitineraire();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: i'm waiting for a response, i don't know how to deal with it

Comment: Can you add your code for getting that list?

Comment: here is my code (up)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this is an example not complete source code.

Step 1:
You must change the json format like this :

```
{ 
   "Android" :
            [
               {
                  "song_name":"Gimme Dat",
                  "song_id":"1932",
                  "artist_name":"Sidney Samson (Feat. Pitbull & Akon)"
               }, 
               {
                  "song_name":"F-k The Money (Remix)",
                  "song_id":"73",
                  "artist_name":"B.o.B. (Feat. Wiz Khalifa)"
               }
             ] 
}
```

Step 2 :

```
/************  Static JSON data ***********/
        final String strJson = "{ "Android" :[{"song_name":"Gimme Dat",
                                  "song_id":"1932",
                                  "artist_name":"Sidney Samson (Feat. Pitbull & Akon)"
                                },
                                { "song_name":"F-k The Money (Remix)",
                                   "song_id":"73",
                                   "artist_name":"B.o.B. (Feat. Wiz Khalifa)"}] }";
String OutputData = "";
               JSONObject jsonResponse;

               try {

                    /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson);

                    /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. ***/
                    /*******  Returns null otherwise.  *******/
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

                    /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/

                    int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();  

                    for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
                    {
                        /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                        /******* Fetch node values **********/
                        int song_id        = Integer.parseInt(jsonChildNode.optString("song_id").toString());
                        String song_name   = jsonChildNode.optString("song_name").toString();
                        String artist_name = jsonChildNode.optString("artist_name").toString();


                        OutputData += "Node : \n\n     "+ song_id +" | "
                                                        + song_name +" | "
                                                        + artist_name +" \n\n ";
                        //Log.i("JSON parse", song_name);
                   }

                    /************ Show Output on screen/activity **********/

                    output.setText( OutputData );

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: I can't change it it's a web service ... so!

Comment: I just add example for json.And also i mean your output is not in json format.. You need to change output. in your case it is an array don't do anything just an for loop is enough. Consider your output is an int array . e.x int[] x = new int[1234567];
  for (int i=0; i < 1234567; i++ ){
   x[i] = i;
  }
  for (int i= 0; i< x.length; i++){
   System.out.println(x[i]);
  }

Comment: i validate it in a json validator and it's ok with it. now if it is a simple array, how can i get it from the url

Comment: You just need an for loop that is enough for e.g
for(int i=0; i<your_array.length; i++){
long value = your_array[i]
} try this

Comment: and how to download it with http?